# Create Windows 7 bootable usb without unetbootin, winusb, or ms-sys?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, live-usb, gparted

How can I create a bootable windows 7 usb without Unetbootin, winusb, or ms-sys? It is the windows 7 ultimate sp1 disc.

I have tried the following:

- using **gparted**, create ntfs partition
- manually copy windows files over to usb
- [followed these steps:](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html)

> B. UEFI bootable
>
> Not all Windows versions are supported. Windows 7 on 64 bits, Windows 8 and newer versions should work.
>
> After the copy process is finished, look in the USB root folder for the efi/boot directory. If there's a bootx64.efi or bootia32.efi file there, then you're done. You can boot from your USB in UEFI mode.
>
> If the OS you are making a bootable USB for is Windows 7, browse the efi/microsoft folder and copy the entire boot folder from this path one level up in the efi folder. Merge folders if boot already exists.
>
> Here is what to do if you don't have the bootx64.efi file in efi/boot folder. Browse into the mounted Windows ISO image into the sources folder. Open install.wim with your archive manager (you will need 7z installed). Go to the path ./1/Windows/Boot/EFI and extract the file bootmgfw.efi anywhere you want. Rename it to bootx64.efi and put it on the USB drive, in the efi/boot folder. If you can't find bootmgfw.efi in install.wim then you probably have a 32 bit Windows ISO or other types of images (recovery disks, upgrade versions).
>
> You can now boot from your USB in UEFI mode.

- umount the device

Now I plug the usb into the machine, boot it up, and all I see is a black screen with a blinking underscore.

Why isn't this working?

I have also tried **dd** to copy the files over to usb, but this ended up causing the usb to be read-only and brought more trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. 
All I did is went to a friend place(he has windows) with the image file in a usb drive and a blank usb drive for making the bootable drive. I opened [Rufus 2.9](https://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-2.9.exe) and from there I made the bootable usb drive in only 5 minutes.
You can use a friends pc for 5 minutes, cant you?
Alternate solution I prefer is, install wine and run rufus in it. then the process is the same.

Comment: I gave up after 6 hours of doing various things. Rufus worked, but I used a windows machine to do it as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.etcher.io/

http://wiki.rosalab.ru/en/index.php/ROSA_ImageWriter

https://rufus.akeo.ie/    if you want to create from windows

First two always works for me... you could give them a try